# proc transpose before merge? dealing with medications in claim database

Tags: merge, sas, transpose

I am dealing with medications in claim database. To make this easier to understand, lets take the following as an example:

```html
patients id   dx1
1              224
2              323
3              432
4              423
   


dataset 2
patients id    date              med_id
1            10/12/2005          54678   
1            01/2/2005           09849
1            05/04/2004
1
2
2
2
3
4
4
4
4
```

My question is regarding merging the two datasets. The first one has one observation per id, the second one can have from 1-200 or more per id. What is the best way to combine both data, would you transpose before joining the two datasets?

Comment: What do you want it to look like after the merge?

Comment: I want to keep all patients from dataset 1 (left merge by patient id) but at the same time I want to be able to keep all rows per patient in dataset 2 so basically it will look like dataset 2 except that  I am keeping the id's that appear only in dataset1.

Answer (score 0):

This will be a full outer join - no row will be deleted from either side.

```
Proc sort data=d1 ;
  By patient_id ;
Run ;

Proc sort data=d2 ;
  By patient_id ;
Run ;

Data d3 ;
  Merge d1 d2 ;
  By patient_id ;
Run ;
```

If you want a left outer join - all rows from d1 and only their match, if any, from d2 - then use this data step instead.

```
Data d3 ;
  Merge d1 (in=in1) d2 ;
  By patient_id ;
  If in1 ;
Run ;
```